# Can Fail2Ban recognise failed logins to locked accounts?

Tags: fail2ban

I have locked the root account on my server with `passwd -l root` and so an attempted login results in the following in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
User root not allowed because account is locked
```

Fail2Ban does not pick these up and so the attempts continue for extended periods. How can I adjust Fail2Ban to recognise these?

Full message example:

```
Apr 10 13:32:28 server sshd[pid]: User root not allowed because account is locked
```

Comment: Is that the full message? If not can you supply an example of the full message. Without a <HOST> block there is little fail2ban can do.

Comment: Generally, you get 3 different messages, none of which seem to cause fail2ban to ban the IP:

`Jan 11 11:19:54 <hostname> sshd[19285]: User root not allowed because account is locked`

`Jan 11 11:19:54 <hostname> sshd[19285]: Received disconnect from 61.184.247.3 port 39292:11:  [preauth]`

`Jan 11 11:19:54 <hostname> sshd[19285]: Disconnected from invalid user root 61.184.247.3 port 39292 [preauth]`

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to block all IPs that try to login as root?  I would imagine most non-targeted hacking attempts will first try logging in as root then try enough non-existent accounts to get the IP banned.

If this isn't the case maybe you should change your approach.

I think a better option than locking root altogether would be to disable external login as root through sshd's config.  That may result in attempts to login as root triggering a security message that fail2ban can use.

Answer (score 0):

Fail2ban will not be able to work with the information provided as there is no <HOST> information for it to block.

<HOST> information is an IP Address or hostname from which the attack takes place, fail2ban uses this information to update the firewall configuration, without it there is nothing to do.